# How to define dynamic field for graphql

Tags: graphql, nestjs

I'd like to use nestjs code first approach to generate scheme and I have a class with a dynamic field.

```
@ObjectType({ description: 'project' })
export class Project extends BaseModel {

  @Field()
  formSelectOrder: Partial<Record<UserRole, OrderStatus[]>>;

}
```

Is it possible to use it somehow with graphql. Now I should define the type to generate the scheme, but since it is dynamic as its value, i cannot add it. Furthermore i don't want to query its values one by one. The only thing I found for it is a custom scalar but because it is only used here it seems a bit overkilling. I could use the JSON scalar as well, but i lose the type at the frontend.

Thanks